# failing to return vector sets{} in full

Tags: c++, vector

My return value v; is only returning a single set{}:

output:

```
198397652
2014-11-14 15:10:10
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
198397652
2014-11-14 15:10:10
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
```

expected output:

```
198397652
2014-11-14 15:10:10
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
198397685
2014-11-14 15:10:13
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
198398295
2014-11-14 15:11:14
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
203440061
2014-11-21 16:13:13
Sell
0.00825550
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000826
```

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>


std::vector<std::string> getmybuyData()
{
        FILE *fp = stdio;
        if (fp == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
        char buydbuff[BUFSIZ];
        bool more = true;
        do{
                std::vector<std::string> v;
                for (int i=0; (i < 7) && (more = (fgets(buydbuff, BUFSIZ, fp) != NULL)); ++i){
                        size_t n = strlen(buydbuff);
                        if (n && buydbuff[n - 1] == '\n') buydbuff[n - 1] = '\0';
                        v.push_back(buydbuff);
                        //return v;
                }
                for(int p = 0; p < v.size(); ++p){
                        std::cout << v[p] << std::endl;
                }
        return v;
        } while (more);
}

std::vector<std::string> markData(){
        std::vector<std::string> vd;
        vd = getmybuyData();
        for (int j=0; j < vd.size(); ++j)
        {
                std::cout << vd[j] << std::endl; //main goal is to print data here.
        }

        return vd;
}
int main()
{
        markData();
}
```

My code is supposed to be gathering a number of record sets{} from a vector but will only return one set{} or segment fault or both. depending on the version. 
. std::cout << vd[j] is where I am trying to print my data to.
How do I return all of the records and not just one?

Note:
std::cout << v[p] << std::endl; 'will' print out all values with a segment fault 'if' I comment out the return v.

[link gdb output](https://bpaste.net/show/979616b1778d)

Comment: In the `getmybuyData` function, you unconditionally return from the function inside the outer (the `do while`) loop.

Comment: Regarding your segmentation fault, run in a debugger, it will stop at the location of the crash and let you examine (and walk up) the function call stack as well as the values of variables.

Comment: And if you don't return anything from `markData`, you will have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You *do* build with extra warnings enabled? If not, add e.g. `-Wall -Wextra` when building.

Comment: adding return vd; to markData got rid of the segment fault. still only returning one record though. Thanks for the tip with  -Wall -Wextra

Comment: Well, if you don't return anything from a function that should return something, then you have undefined behavior, which often leads to crashes or other weird behavior. And I mean that if you remove the existing `return` statement in `getmybuyData`, then you don't return anything at all, which will cause problems in `markData` where you expect `getmybuyData` to return something.

Comment: There are no significant warnings and no error, but still only returning 1 set.   :(

Comment: Read the first comment from Joachim again.

Comment: `getmybuyData` does `return v;` at the end of the first loop iteration

Comment: no matter where I try, that return won't work.   http://i.imgur.com/rAuRmUP.png